# Setting Emacs Tramp to store local backups

Tags: linux, emacs, ftp, backup, tramp

I love emacs, but something has been nagging me. I can't seem to get emacs to store local backups of files when I am editing them via tramp.

Currently, when I edit a local file a set of old versions is stored in the /tmp/myusername/emacs_backup folder. However, when I am FTPing via tramp, old versions aren't stored there (I assume it is trying to store them remotely?).

Here are my .emacs settings:

```
(defvar user-temporary-file-directory  
  (concat "/tmp/" user-login-name "/emacs_backup/"))  
(make-directory user-temporary-file-directory t)  
(setq make-backup-files t)  
(setq backup-by-copying t)  
(setq version-control t)  
(setq delete-old-versions t)  
(setq kept-new-versions 10)  
(setq backup-directory-alist `(("." . ,user-temporary-file-directory)))  
(setq tramp-backup-directory-alist backup-directory-alist)  
(setq tramp-auto-save-directory user-temporary-file-directory)  
(setq auto-save-list-file-prefix
      (concat user-temporary-file-directory ".auto-saves-"))  
(setq auto-save-file-name-transforms  
      `((".*" ,user-temporary-file-directory t)))
```

I don't care if tramp su editing is also stored in the tmp folder - the more the merrier in my opinion. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 3):

The documentation for `tramp-backup-directory-alist` says

> (setq tramp-backup-directory-alist backup-directory-alist)
>
> gives the same backup policy for Tramp files on their hosts like the policy for local files.

Which I would interpret as backing up tramp files on the remote machine ("their host"). Looking at the implementation in `tramp.el` this is also the default implementation (if `tramp-backup-directory-alist` isn't set, then `backup-directory-alist` is).

Tramp assumes that a backup of a remote file should always be remote too, and explicitly prepends the method/user/host bits before doing the backup. If you want to change the behavior I think you'll have to advise `tramp-handle-find-backup-file-name` to adjust the file name (so it's a valid local one) and to coordinate with an entry in `backup-directory-alist`.

FWIW: Putting backup in the temporary file directory isn't going to help much in the long run. "Temporary" kind of defeats the purpose of backups.

Answer (score 2):

I was also trying to store backups locally.  I submitted a [bug](https://debbugs.gnu.org/cgi/bugreport.cgi?bug=28959) because I thought `tramp-backup-directory-alist` was broken.  After talking to Michael Albinus, I found out that I misunderstood `tramp-backup-directory-alist`, which is a way to store remote backups of remote files, and that I should instead do:

```
(add-to-list 'backup-directory-alist
             (cons tramp-file-name-regexp "/my/local/backup/"))
```

Answer (score 1):

I was able to find a workaround (I tried setting it up via tramp-backup-directory-alist - but apparently there is a with tramp's ability to locally save remote buffers) . Rather than using the built-in backup, I found the elisp script called: [backup-each-save.el](http://www.mail-archive.com/gnu-emacs-sources@gnu.org/msg00182.html) written by Benjamin Rutt.

Answer (score 1):

Redefining `trump-handle-find-backup-file-name` works for me.  It gets rid of the behavior that wants to save the backups on the remote server.

```
(defun tramp-handle-find-backup-file-name (filename)
      "Like `find-backup-file-name' for Tramp files."
      (with-parsed-tramp-file-name filename nil
        (tramp-run-real-handler 'find-backup-file-name (list filename))))
```

Answer (score 0):

Tl;dr: I have the following settings, Tramp backups remote file to my local directory.

```lisp
(setq backup-directory-alist '(("." . "~/.emacs.d/tmp")))
(setq tramp-backup-directory-alist nil)
```

Explanation:

According to the implementation of Tramp 2.6.1.5,

```lisp
(let ((backup-directory-alist
   (if tramp-backup-directory-alist
       (mapcar
    (lambda (x)
      (cons
       (car x)
       (if (and (stringp (cdr x))
           (file-name-absolute-p (cdr x))
           (not (tramp-tramp-file-p (cdr x))))
          (tramp-make-tramp-file-name v (cdr x))
         (cdr x))))
    tramp-backup-directory-alist)
     backup-directory-alist))
  result)
  ...
)
```

The logic here reads

- if `tramp-backup-directory-alist` is set, then tramp tries to append the tramp file prefix, i.e., host/user/..., to each of the backup directory if the directory satisfies three conditions:

  1. is a string,
  2. is an absolute path, and
  3. not a tramp path.
- Otherwise, use `backup-directory-alist` without modification.